# El código no optimiza las imágenes que son mayores a 2 mb

Tags: php, html

He estado buscando una manera de optimizar las imágenes bajándole la calidad y el tamaño dado que la pagina que estoy creando cuenta con una galería, y se suelen subir imágenes que llegan hasta los 5 o 6 mb y hasta el momento encontré un código que funciona sin embargo al subir una imagen mas grande de 2mb me manda un error de fichero no valido. le he estado dando varias vueltas al código pero no se porque se muestra ese mensaje ya que la validación no es sobre el tamaño del archivo si no mas sobre el formato(jpg,jpeg,png)

ESTE ES EL ARCHIVO PHP:

```php
<?php 


if(isset($_FILES['images']))
{

    //Funciones optimizar imagenes



    //Ruta de la carpeta donde se guardarán las imagenes
    $patch='imagenes';


    //Parámetros optimización, resolución máxima permitida
    $max_ancho = 1280;
    $max_alto = 900;


    if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/png' || $_FILES['images']['type']=='image/jpeg' || $_FILES['images']['type']=='image/gif'|| $_FILES['images']['type']=='image/JPG')
    {


        $medidasimagen= getimagesize($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']);

        //Si las imagenes tienen una resolución y un peso aceptable se suben tal cual
        if($medidasimagen[0] < 1280 && $_FILES['images']['size'] < 100000)
        {

            $nombrearchivo=$_FILES['images']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], $patch.'/'.$nombrearchivo);   
        }
        //Si no, se generan nuevas imagenes optimizadas
        else 
        {

            $nombrearchivo=$_FILES['images']['name'];

            //Redimensionar
            $rtOriginal=$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];

            if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/jpeg')
            {
                $original = imagecreatefromjpeg($rtOriginal);
            }
            else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/png')
            {
                $original = imagecreatefrompng($rtOriginal);
            }
            else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/gif')
            {
                $original = imagecreatefromgif($rtOriginal);
            }


            list($ancho,$alto)=getimagesize($rtOriginal);

            $x_ratio = $max_ancho / $ancho;
            $y_ratio = $max_alto / $alto;


            if( ($ancho <= $max_ancho) && ($alto <= $max_alto) )
            {
                $ancho_final = $ancho;
                $alto_final = $alto;
            }
            elseif (($x_ratio * $alto) < $max_alto)
            {
                $alto_final = ceil($x_ratio * $alto);
                $ancho_final = $max_ancho;
            }
            else
            {
                $ancho_final = ceil($y_ratio * $ancho);
                $alto_final = $max_alto;
            }

            $lienzo=imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_final,$alto_final); 

            imagecopyresampled($lienzo,$original,0,0,0,0,$ancho_final, $alto_final,$ancho,$alto);

            //imagedestroy($original);

            $cal=8;

            if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/jpeg' || $_FILES['images']['type']=='image/jpg')
            {
                imagejpeg($lienzo,$patch."/".$nombrearchivo);
            }
            else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/png')
            {
                imagepng($lienzo,$patch."/".$nombrearchivo);
            }
            else if($_FILES['images']['type']=='image/gif')
            {
                imagegif($lienzo,$patch."/".$nombrearchivo);
            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
     echo 'fichero no soportado';
    }

}
?>
```

ESTE ES HTML

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="formulario-grupo">
    <label for="images">Cargar imagen</label>
    <input type="file" name="images" id="images" accept="image/*">  
</div>

<div class="formulario-grupo">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" class="boton">
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has revisado la configuracion del php.ini sobre el limite de subida en archivos: upload_max_filesize = 2M

Porque si el codigo te permite subir imagenes sin problemas pero te muestra un error por esa capacidad verifica el archivo de configuracion php.ini

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Comment: gracias por responder antes que nada, ahora sobre la configuracion ya de antemano lo habia cambiado de 2mb a 6mb y sin embargo sigue saliendo ese mensaje.

Comment: En la condicion del primer if() hay un tipo de imagen que esta en mayuscula: $_FILES['images']['type']=='image/JPG' los demas estan en minusculas, he probado el codigo y me funcion en el servidor local con imagenes jpeg de hasta 7 mb y no he aparece el error.

Comment: enserio entonces sera por otra razon?

Comment: Puede ser una posibilidad, porque si envia el error que aparece en el reporte como reporte echo 'fichero no soportado'; al final del if() entonces es que no reconoce el tipo de imagen.